# A quote for a relieving loss of a loved one

Tags: classical-latin, passage-request

Is there a poem or other passage of classical Latin about the following sentiment?
I prefer poetry, but good hits in prose are also welcome.
It need not — and indeed should not — be the same word for word, but capture the essence of a similar set of emotions.

A loved one has been ill for a long time and has finally passed away.
Although there is sorrow of loss, the relief for their suffering coming to an end is far stronger.

(This is not something I am going through at the moment, but someone else I know.)

Comment: There's definitely at least one letter by Pliny that addresses this scenario, and I believe it even includes a pithy little saying or two to summarize. I'll try to dig it up later this evening.

Comment: @cnread If you (or anyone else) can find that passage in Pliny, that would be great, even though I just accepted another answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One part of Evander's speech of mourning for his son Pallas can be taken out of context to convey the sentiment you are aiming for:

> 'non haec, o Palla, dederas promissa parenti,
>   cautius ut saeuo uelles te credere Marti.
>   haud ignarus eram quantum noua gloria in armis
>   et praedulce decus primo certamine posset.
>   primitiae iuuenis miserae bellique propinqui
>   dura rudimenta, et nulli exaudita deorum
>   uota precesque meae! **tuque, o sanctissima coniunx,
>
>   felix morte tua neque in hunc seruata dolorem!**
>   contra ego uiuendo uici mea fata, superstes
>   restarem ut genitor. (*Aeneid* XI.152-61)

In context, Evander means that his wife is lucky that death spared her from the sorrow of seeing her son die. I see no reason, though, that we can't construe "in hunc servata dolorem" as referring to the difficult last days of an illness.